# Which Oracle JDBC driver to use with Java for developing Web Apps

Tags: java, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g and the Java version 1.7

I want to have secure data connectivity. i have used ojdb6.jar driver but later i heard about ojdbc14.

So i was wondering which version to use..

THanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the `ojdbc6.jar`, it's for Java versions 6 and up. `ojdbc14.jar` is for use with Java 1.4.

As far as I can tell, Oracle is no longer releasing Java 1.4 drivers for Oracle 11g. I can only find Java 5 and Java 6 drivers.